# Call function for each controller

Tags: angularjs

I have couple of pages and couple of controllers. And I want to call function for each of those page. How can I do it in angular without copy-pasted all those code in each controller?

Comment: Could you add this function to the $rootScope?

Comment: Create service and inject them to each controller of the views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use service to share data/functions between controllers. below is just an example

```
app.factory('theService', function() {  
    return {
        customers: {},
        getCustomer : function(){ //some code }
    };
});

app.controller("DashboardCtrl", function($scope, theService) {
    theService.customers = $scope.customers;
    theService.getCustomer();
});

app.controller("ClientCtrl", function($scope, theService) { 
    $scope.customers = theService.customers; 
    theService.getCustomer();
});
```